# Calling a method and returning to an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm working on a program and it involves arrays. I'm new to this so I keep writing code and deleting it over and over.

I need to ask the user to input a number from 1 to 99.

Their input should allocate the size of a single dim array.

Then I have to send that array to a method that randomly chooses DOUBLES from 55 to 100 and place them into the array.

This is what I'm playing around with now. I'm starting to confuse myself!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int scores = 0;
    int numberOfGrades;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter a number of grades from 1 to 99: ");
    numberOfGrades = input.nextInt();

    int[] amountOfGrades = new int[numberOfGrades];

    randomGrades(amountOfGrades);

    System.out.print("The letter grades for each score are: ");

} //End Method


   /**
    * 
    * @param array
    * @return
    */
    public static int randomGrades(int[] array) {
        for (int cntr = 55; cntr < 100; cntr++) {
            int rndm = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
            return array[rndm];

        }//End Main Method
```

Comment: What's your question? Your problem statement says you want an array of `double` but your code creates an array of `int`. I honestly don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: a) your `return array[rndm];` is in your loop and so there will only be one iteration b) I think you want to return an array not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.util.Random;

public class DoubleArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfGrades = 10;
        int[] grades = generateRandomGrades(numberOfGrades);
        for (int grade : grades){
            System.out.println(grade);
        }
    }

    private static int[] generateRandomGrades(int numberOfGrades) {
        int[] grades = new int[numberOfGrades];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++){
            grades[i] = new Random().nextInt(45)+55;
        }
        return grades;
    }
}
```

It generates an array of size 10 and stores a new random value between 55 inclusive and 100 exclusive inside each element of the array.

Comment: I do not understand the negative vote or the delete request. It does exactly what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
public static double[] randomGrades(double[] array) {
    Random rndm = new Random(); // creating Random outside of the for loop, not in each iteration in for-loop to save memory
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each element of an array
        array[i] = (double) (rndm.nextInt(45) + rndm.nextDouble() + 55);
    }
    return array; // return array of doubles
}
```

Also change the following line in the `main()` method, from:

`int[] amountOfGrades = new int[numberOfGrades];`

to:

```
double[] amountOfGrades = new double[numberOfGrades];
```

as you said in question that you want to store `double` valuees instead of `int`s.

### Explanation of the for-loop:

```
array[i] = (double) (rndm.nextInt(45) + rndm.nextDouble() + 55);
```

`rndm.nextInt(45)` returns `int` from 0(inclusive) to 45(exclusive),

`rndm.nextDouble()` returns `double` from 0.0(inclusive) to 1.0(exclusive)

**Min** possible value: 0 + 0.0 + 55 = 55

**Max** possible value: 44 + 1.0 + 55 = 100 (note  that random `double` is not exactly 1.0 as it's exclusive, but it's any other possible `double` value close to 1.0 due to huge `double` precision

---

### Edit:

With line `randomGrades(amountOfGrades);`, you create random double values and store them in an array, but you neither print these values to the console nor assign these values to an array:
You might want to consider changing this line:

`randomGrades(amountOfGrades);`

to:

```
amountOfGrades = randomGrades(amountOfGrades); // that way you have access to result doubke values later
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(amountOfGrades));
```

### Whole working program:

Ok, I include whole solution for your convenience, but try not to copy it blindly, try to understand what's happening here (if you need to pass `int` value to `randomGrades()` instead of `double[]` as argument, uncomment all comments that I included and delete parts that are not necessary):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int scores = 0;
        int numberOfGrades;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter amount:");
        numberOfGrades = input.nextInt();

        double[] amountOfGrades = new double[numberOfGrades];
        amountOfGrades = randomGrades(amountOfGrades /* or: amountOfGrades.length */);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(amountOfGrades));

        System.out.println("Letter grades...");

    }

    public static double[] randomGrades(double[] array /* or: int amount */) {
        Random rndm = new Random();
        // add this line if you use int argument: double[] array = new double[amount];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (double)(rndm.nextInt(45) + rndm.nextDouble() + 55);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I change int to double in the main method Java tells me that this is an incompatible type and a double cannot convert to an int (even though I no longer have an int).

Comment: Also, the program is telling me the method length cannot be found where I have array.length

Comment: @eazy Ok I changed `.length()` to `.length`. In which exactly line do you have problem that you explained in first comment? For me everything works now just fine.

Comment: @eazy I included whole working solution at the end of my answer, you might want to have a look at it.

Comment: Everything is working just fine, I appreciate all of the help! I just can't figure out the one part where it says                               System.out.println("Arrays.toString(amountOfGrades)); Java keeps telling me Java cannot find symbol "Arrays"

Comment: @eazy If you type it exactly as you have shown in your comment, you should delete this `"` character. It should not be there. I made a little shortcut, you're right - Arrays is a class from `java.util` package. At the very beginning of this file, type `import java.util.*` to import this class. If you wouldn't want to use this convenience method, you can create a loop printing all elements: `for(double d : amountOfGrades) { System.out.println(d + ", "); }